# Adjective for someone who's quick and easy to become close to

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a 1 word adjective to describe someone who very easily builds close and personal relationships with other people, in a way that almost seems magical to everyone else.
Charismatic is close, but not quite, as this person doesn't necessarily inspire devotion or admiration, just quickly becomes people's best friends.
The closest word I've found is "palsy-walsy", meaning someone friendly in an intimate/hearty way. It doesn't quite describe the effect it has on the people around them though.

Comment: Melody Liu, you seem to be mixing several different ideas.

“Charismatic” does match what you described and doesn’t at all suffer from “inspiring devotion or admiration.” Meanwhile, “palsy-walsy" is almost the opposite of what you asked about; it always describes a *semblance* of friendship with no substance.

Answer (score 1):

**Accessible** is often used to describe someone who others find easy to talk to or open up to.  [*Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessible) describes it as easy to speak to or deal with.

**Approachable** has a similar meaning: easy to meet or deal with (and "accessible" is used in the definition) [*Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approachable)

Answer (score 0):

**Amiable charisma** can be used in the context provided by you in your explanation.

[***Amiable***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amiable) (adjective):

> **friendly**, sociable, and congenial. *Example:* "an amiable host."

[***Charisma***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charisma) (noun):

> A special **magnetic charm** or appeal. *Example:* "the charisma of a popular actor."

"***Amiable charisma***" is used in various books to describe a person who has ***friendly disposition with magnetic charm***.

1) [THE COMMON CASE OF DAMIAN VONGCIR](https://books.google.com/books?id=WcK7AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%22Amiable+charisma%22&source=bl&ots=P7spm_D-Dw&sig=8dGoSHqsDzY1mCQl7JvOGy4N_U0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidqoGtgdjcAhUDOisKHclqCIEQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Amiable%20charisma%22&f=false)
By Uyi Eguavoen.

> > *When Damian first came to Landmark, it was Macaulay Etiebet who was so often talked about, and it was his **amiable charisma**, his stylish sophistication, and appealing elegance that got the most mentions.*

2) [9 Sisters Cursed Since Birth: A Corrupt Family Drowning in Their Deadly Sins](https://books.google.com/books?id=FcxHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT192&lpg=PT192&dq=%22Amiable+charisma%22&source=bl&ots=4SPb3QPTbX&sig=Xp1btIWMVywSoeePsJuBNzEizCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1rObLgNjcAhVQT30KHfFMC0wQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Amiable%20charisma%22&f=false) By Na 'Veah Rose

> > *I describe Lannah as a charming person, but she can be a victimizer as well. Meaning -- she has the potential of intriguing and enticing people with her **amiable charisma**.*

3) [Born Under Punches](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Qw3AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT58&lpg=PT58&dq=%22amiable+charisma%22&source=bl&ots=nrzaNHpPtw&sig=nVlSxYWtGhx7UTEIeJVNLjcUt0c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvoMT4gdjcAhXHTn0KHXHmCKEQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22amiable%20charisma%22&f=false) By Martyn Waites

> > *It was clear to Larkin, even in the short time he had been there, that Tony Woodhouse was popular with both staff and clients. He had an easy, **amiable charisma** people responded to.*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word **magnetic:**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magnetic

> possessing an extraordinary power or ability to attract; a magnetic personality

The synonyms for “magnetic” cited here are also a fantastic collection to choose from to describe a person who easily draws others in and manages to connect with them in a deep and meaningful way.

> alluring, appealing, attractive, bewitching, captivating, charismatic, charming, elfin, enchanting, engaging, entrancing, fascinating, fetching, glamorous (also glamourous), luring, seductive

**Update (8/7/2018):** Another suggestion could be **gregarious,** which can indicate someone who easily converses with others and is comfortable to be around (see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gregarious, especially "b"):

> a : tending to associate with others of one's kind : social gregarious animals
>
> b : marked by or indicating a liking for companionship : sociable is friendly, outgoing, and gregarious
>
> c : of or relating to a social group